# GWT Style CellTable Header

Tags: css, gwt, header, styling, celltable

I'm adding a column that has a color, the default styling has margins that are too wide. I've added a styling to fix that. This works, until I specify a header (I don't want any header text, but to keep column sorting from messing up, apparently I have to specify, so its "").

What happens is that the header causes the whole column to be too wide again. However, how do I change this header's styling? I don't really want to change all the headers though.

```
colorColumn.setCellStyleNames("SkinnyColumn");
table.addColumn(colorColumn, "");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't seem like this is possible with GWT 2.4.0.

With 2.5 however, `Header` has a new [`getHeaderStyleNames`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/Header.html#getHeaderStyleNames%28%29) ∕ [`setHeaderStyleNames`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/Header.html#setHeaderStyleNames%28java.lang.String%29).

And if that's not enough, you can have complete control on what's being generated through the `CellTableBuilder`, `HeaderBuilder` and `FooterBuilder`.